# Geometry, Quaternions, Rotations

Tags: geometry, rotations, quaternions

For a coordinate system $C_2$, if I have the angles made by its coordinate axes ($x_2$,$y_2$ and $z_2$) with the coordinate axes($x_1$, $y_1$ and $z_1$) respectively of another coordinate system $C_1$, how do I find the rotation matrix or the rotation quaternion required to move from the coordinate system $C_1$ to $ C_2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The rotation matrix you're looking for is, I believe, the Direction Cosine Matrix. Once you have that, it's possible to obtain the quaternion too, with a method proposed by Sheppard & Natanson.